# MapStruct requires Impl class

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have next classes:

**Mapper**

```
public interface DeviceTokensMapper {

    DeviceTokensMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DeviceTokensMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "tokenName", target = "tokenName"),
            @Mapping(source = "userOsType", target = "osType"),
    })

    DeviceTokensDTO toDeviceTokensDTO(DeviceTokens deviceTokens);
}
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class DeviceTokens {

    @Id
    @Column(name="token_name", nullable = false)
    private String tokenName;

    @Column(name = "os", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated
    private UserOSType userOsType;

    public DeviceTokens() {}

    public DeviceTokens(String tokenName, UserOSType userOSType) {
        this.tokenName = tokenName;
        this.userOsType = userOSType;
    }

    public String getTokenName() {
        return tokenName;
    }

    public void setTokenName(String tokenName) {
        this.tokenName = tokenName;
    }

    public UserOSType getUserOsType() {
        return userOsType;
    }

    public void setUserOsType(UserOSType userOsType) {
        this.userOsType = userOsType;
    }
}
```

**DTO:**

```
public class DeviceTokensDTO {

    private String tokenName;

    private UserOSType osType;

    public DeviceTokensDTO() {}

    public DeviceTokensDTO(String tokenName, UserOSType osType) {
        this.tokenName = tokenName;
        this.osType = osType;
    }

    public UserOSType getOsType() {
        return osType;
    }

    public void setOsType(UserOSType osType) {
        this.osType = osType;
    }

    public String getTokenName() {
        return tokenName;
    }

    public void setTokenName(String tokenName) {
        this.tokenName = tokenName;
    }
}
```

And method from **spring service** class where I use this mapping:

```
@Transactional
public DeviceTokensDTO storeToken(String tokenId, UserOSType userOsType) {
    DeviceTokens deviceTokens = new DeviceTokens(tokenId, userOsType);
    DeviceTokens newDevice = deviceTokensRepository.save(deviceTokens);

    return DeviceTokensMapper.INSTANCE.toDeviceTokensDTO(newDevice);
}
```

When I run above method I see next exception:

> ERROR [dispatcherServlet]:? - Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   dto.DeviceTokensMapperImpl

So why mapper require implementation class? Could please someone advise?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MapStruct generates code at compile time, and the call to `Mappers.getMapper(DeviceTokensMapper.class);` will look for the generated implementation of the mapper interface. For some reason it seems to be missing in your deployment unit (WAR etc.).

Btw. when working with Spring as your DI container, you can use `@Mapper(componentModel="spring")` and you will be able to obtain mapper instances via dependency injection instead of using the `Mappers` factory.

Comment: I have added both component model and put map struct processor but still im getting Cannot find implementation for ABCMapper which is Mappper interface

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: `target/generated-sources` is empty :[

Comment: I upgraded `maven-compiler-plugin` to `3.6.0` then it kicked in... it was an older version before

Comment: upgrading maven-compiler-plugin version from 2.5.1 to 3.6.1 helped

Comment: In kotlin still I have issue.

Answer (score 33):

if you use maven, you need to add mapstruct-processor dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It did the job for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Do you have both **mapstruct-processor-xx** and **mapstruct-xx** libraries included in your project?

I had the same problem and I realized that I forgot to include mapstruct-processor-xx.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using Maven? If yes, then most probably you have missed the mapstruct-processor configuration under the maven compiler plugin.

The proper configuration is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId> <!-- use mapstruct-jdk8 for Java 8 or higher -->
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <target>1.6</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Project lombok along with mapstruct then you will need to configure both under maven compiler plugin, as both of them generate source at compile time.

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have met the same problem in my project with gradle. And I replace the `build.gradel` 
from

```
compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.2.0.CR2'
```

to

```
compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.1.0.Final'
```

Then sh build clean&build. It works now!

Answer (score 3):

In your Mapper class, use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`

and to generate Impl classes using mapstruct, you need both of following dependencies.

```
        <!-- Dependencies for Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle add

```
compile group: 'org.mapstruct',name: 'mapstruct-jdk8',version: 1.2.0.Final



annotationProcessor group: 'org.mapstruct',name: 'mapstruct-processor',version: 1.2.0.Final
```

Enable annotation Processing in your setting

Bonus : add plugin intellij for mapstruct

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had wrapped `<plugin>` within `<pluginManagement>` tags to workaround an eclipse (Mars) bug as follows

```
<pluginManagement>
 <plugin> ... </plugin> 
</pluginManagement>
```

Removing `<pluginManagement>` tags fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I didn't run `./gradlew clean build` (`gradlew.bat` for Windows) after creating/editing the mapper class or related classes.

Also, something I found was useful is `./gradlew clean build -x test` works, but doesn't run all your test, which was a lot in my case.